# Hyperledger Fabric - unable to instantiate - Missing contract org.hyperledger.fabric in metadata

Tags: docker, hyperledger-fabric

I followed the [documentation](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/developapps/application.html) for the Commercial paper, but stuck at instantiation.

I used Fabric 1.4, tried to search online, but have not find anyone has the problem, which could be related to `Error: ["Missing contract org.hyperledger.fabric in metadata"]`

When I run

```
docker exec cliMagnetoCorp peer chaincode instantiate -n papercontract -v 0 -l node -c '{"Args":["org.papernet.commercialpaper:instantiate"]}' -C mychannel -P "AND ('Org1MSP.member')"
```

I got this:

```
2019-04-25 16:11:24.620 UTC [chaincodeCmd] InitCmdFactory -> INFO 001 Get chain(mychannel) orderer endpoint: orderer.example.com:7050
2019-04-25 16:11:24.622 UTC [chaincodeCmd] checkChaincodeCmdParams -> INFO 002 Using default escc
2019-04-25 16:11:24.623 UTC [chaincodeCmd] checkChaincodeCmdParams -> INFO 003 Using default vscc
Error: Error endorsing chaincode: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = timeout expired while starting chaincode papercontract:0(networkid:dev,peerid:peer0.org1.example.com,tx:b72dd3f848069660d7cf8c783008c2d8896ff4d4329eecfc8e2405966d0bff10)
```

docker ps

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                        COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                                            NAMES
94678322b1d2        hyperledger/fabric-tools     "/bin/bash"              19 minutes ago      Up 19 minutes                                                        cliMagnetoCorp
3083be9ec849        gliderlabs/logspout          "/bin/logspout"          20 minutes ago      Up 20 minutes       127.0.0.1:8000->80/tcp                           logspout
3380437d78dd        hyperledger/fabric-peer      "peer node start"        21 minutes ago      Up 21 minutes       0.0.0.0:7051->7051/tcp, 0.0.0.0:7053->7053/tcp   peer0.org1.example.com
b4ecdd45d01a        hyperledger/fabric-couchdb   "tini -- /docker-ent…"   21 minutes ago      Up 21 minutes       4369/tcp, 9100/tcp, 0.0.0.0:5984->5984/tcp       couchdb
cccf5c6bd853        hyperledger/fabric-ca        "sh -c 'fabric-ca-se…"   21 minutes ago      Up 21 minutes       0.0.0.0:7054->7054/tcp                           ca.example.com
e8a5a59682b1        hyperledger/fabric-orderer   "orderer"                21 minutes ago      Up 21 minutes       0.0.0.0:7050->7050/tcp                           orderer.example.com
```

And logs from logspout:

```
dev-peer0.org1.example.com-papercontract-0|> papercontract@0.0.3 start /usr/local/src
dev-peer0.org1.example.com-papercontract-0|> fabric-chaincode-node start "--peer.address" "peer0.org1.example.com:7052"
dev-peer0.org1.example.com-papercontract-0|
dev-peer0.org1.example.com-papercontract-0|schema $id ignored http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#
dev-peer0.org1.example.com-papercontract-0|schema $id ignored http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#
dev-peer0.org1.example.com-papercontract-0|schema $id ignored http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#
dev-peer0.org1.example.com-papercontract-0|2019-04-25T16:11:26.667Z info [contracts-spi/bootstrap.js]                        info: Metadata validated against schema correctly {"timestamp":"2019-04-25T16:11:26.667Z"}
dev-peer0.org1.example.com-papercontract-0|2019-04-25T16:11:26.668Z info [contracts-spi/bootstrap.js]                        info: Metadata file has been located {"timestamp":"2019-04-25T16:11:26.668Z"}
dev-peer0.org1.example.com-papercontract-0|2019-04-25T16:11:26.669Z info [contracts-spi/chaincodefromcontract.js]            info: Using serializers {"transaction":"jsonSerializer","serializers":{},"timestamp":"2019-04-25T16:11:26.669Z"}
dev-peer0.org1.example.com-papercontract-0|fabric-chaincode-node start --peer.address localhost:7051 --chaincode-id-name mycc
dev-peer0.org1.example.com-papercontract-0|
dev-peer0.org1.example.com-papercontract-0|Options:
dev-peer0.org1.example.com-papercontract-0|  --help                                  Show help  [boolean]
dev-peer0.org1.example.com-papercontract-0|  -v, --version                           Show version number  [boolean]
dev-peer0.org1.example.com-papercontract-0|  --peer.address  [string] [required]
dev-peer0.org1.example.com-papercontract-0|  --grpc.max_send_message_length  [number] [default: -1]
dev-peer0.org1.example.com-papercontract-0|  --grpc.max_receive_message_length  [number] [default: -1]
dev-peer0.org1.example.com-papercontract-0|  --grpc.keepalive_time_ms  [number] [default: 110000]
dev-peer0.org1.example.com-papercontract-0|  --grpc.http2.min_time_between_pings_ms  [number] [default: 110000]
dev-peer0.org1.example.com-papercontract-0|  --grpc.keepalive_timeout_ms  [number] [default: 20000]
dev-peer0.org1.example.com-papercontract-0|  --grpc.http2.max_pings_without_data  [number] [default: 0]
dev-peer0.org1.example.com-papercontract-0|  --grpc.keepalive_permit_without_calls  [number] [default: 1]
dev-peer0.org1.example.com-papercontract-0|  --ssl-target-name-override  [string]
dev-peer0.org1.example.com-papercontract-0|  --chaincode-id-name  [string] [required]
dev-peer0.org1.example.com-papercontract-0|  --module-path  [string] [default: "/usr/local/src"]
dev-peer0.org1.example.com-papercontract-0|
dev-peer0.org1.example.com-papercontract-0|Error: ["Missing contract org.hyperledger.fabric in metadata"]
dev-peer0.org1.example.com-papercontract-0|    at new ChaincodeFromContract (/usr/local/src/node_modules/fabric-shim/lib/contract-spi/chaincodefromcontract.js:63:19)
dev-peer0.org1.example.com-papercontract-0|    at Function.register (/usr/local/src/node_modules/fabric-shim/lib/contract-spi/bootstrap.js:35:27)
dev-peer0.org1.example.com-papercontract-0|    at Function.bootstrap (/usr/local/src/node_modules/fabric-shim/lib/contract-spi/bootstrap.js:49:19)
dev-peer0.org1.example.com-papercontract-0|    at <anonymous>
dev-peer0.org1.example.com-papercontract-0|npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
dev-peer0.org1.example.com-papercontract-0|npm ERR! errno 1
dev-peer0.org1.example.com-papercontract-0|npm ERR! papercontract@0.0.3 start: `fabric-chaincode-node start "--peer.address" "peer0.org1.example.com:7052"`
dev-peer0.org1.example.com-papercontract-0|npm ERR! Exit status 1
dev-peer0.org1.example.com-papercontract-0|npm ERR!
dev-peer0.org1.example.com-papercontract-0|npm ERR! Failed at the papercontract@0.0.3 start script.
dev-peer0.org1.example.com-papercontract-0|npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
dev-peer0.org1.example.com-papercontract-0|
dev-peer0.org1.example.com-papercontract-0|npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
dev-peer0.org1.example.com-papercontract-0|npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2019-04-25T16_11_26_714Z-debug.log
                    peer0.org1.example.com|2019-04-25 16:16:24.311 UTC [chaincode] Launch -> ERRO 03b launchAndWaitForRegister failed: timeout expired while starting chaincode papercontract:0(networkid:dev,peerid:peer0.org1.example.com,tx:b72dd3f848069660d7cf8c783008c2d8896ff4d4329eecfc8e2405966d0bff10)
                       orderer.example.com|2019-04-25 16:16:24.312 UTC [orderer/common/broadcast] Handle -> WARN 019 Error reading from 172.21.0.7:34890: rpc error: code = Canceled desc = context canceled
                    peer0.org1.example.com|github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/chaincode.(*ChaincodeSupport).launchAndWaitForRegister
                    peer0.org1.example.com| /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/chaincode/chaincode_support.go:579
                    peer0.org1.example.com|github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/chaincode.(*ChaincodeSupport).Launch
                    peer0.org1.example.com| /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/chaincode/chaincode_support.go:741
                    peer0.org1.example.com|github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/chaincode.Execute
                    peer0.org1.example.com| /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/chaincode/exectransaction.go:45
                    peer0.org1.example.com|github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/endorser.(*Endorser).callChaincode
                    peer0.org1.example.com| /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/endorser/endorser.go:152
                    peer0.org1.example.com|github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/endorser.(*Endorser).simulateProposal
                    peer0.org1.example.com| /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/endorser/endorser.go:262
                    peer0.org1.example.com|github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/endorser.(*Endorser).ProcessProposal
                    peer0.org1.example.com| /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/endorser/endorser.go:477
                    peer0.org1.example.com|github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/handlers/auth/filter.(*filter).ProcessProposal
                    peer0.org1.example.com| /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/handlers/auth/filter/filter.go:31
                    peer0.org1.example.com|github.com/hyperledger/fabric/protos/peer._Endorser_ProcessProposal_Handler
                    peer0.org1.example.com| /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/protos/peer/peer.pb.go:112
                    peer0.org1.example.com|github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/google.golang.org/grpc.(*Server).processUnaryRPC
                    peer0.org1.example.com| /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/google.golang.org/grpc/server.go:781
                    peer0.org1.example.com|github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/google.golang.org/grpc.(*Server).handleStream
                    peer0.org1.example.com| /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/google.golang.org/grpc/server.go:981
                    peer0.org1.example.com|github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/google.golang.org/grpc.(*Server).serveStreams.func1.1
                    peer0.org1.example.com| /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/google.golang.org/grpc/server.go:551
                    peer0.org1.example.com|runtime.goexit
                    peer0.org1.example.com| /opt/go/src/runtime/asm_amd64.s:2337
```

Comment: would you mind posting the output of `docker ps` please, to check, which containers and which version of fabric is actually running? might lead us to the root cause.

Comment: It looks like release 1.4.1 has broken the commercial paper sample. https://jira.hyperledger.org/browse/FAB-15287 has been raised

Comment: great, thanks for your input @david_k
that's been my gut feeling, too

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Until https://jira.hyperledger.org/browse/FAB-15287 is addressed the workaround for now is to modify the package.json files in the magnetocorp/contract and digibank/contract directories. Look for the entries

```
"dependencies" : {
   "fabric-contract-api" : "~1.4.0",
   "fabric-shim": "~1.4.0"
},
```

and remove the `~` (tilda) from the version numbers ie

```
"dependencies" : {
   "fabric-contract-api" : "1.4.0",
   "fabric-shim": "1.4.0"
},
```

This should revert it back to using 1.4.0 rather than 1.4.1 which at writing is the current 1.4 version and the sample should work.

Comment: A fix has now gone into fabric-samples to remove the contract-metadata directory which was the cause of the problem. If you reclone or re-pull the github repository it should now work without modification