# Issue with instantiating contract as per the MagnetoCorp example

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-chaincode

Whenever I try to instantiate a contract according to the MagnetoCorp example, I receive the following errors. In the terminal:

> $ docker exec cliMagnetoCorp peer chaincode instantiate -n
>   papercontract -v 0 -l node -c
>   '{"Args":["org.papernet.commercialpaper:instantiate"]}' -C mychannel
>   -P "AND ('Org1MSP.member')"
>
> 2019-05-03 06:00:40.396 UTC [chaincodeCmd] InitCmdFactory -> INFO 001
>   Retrieved channel (mychannel) orderer endpoint:
>   orderer.example.com:7050 2019-05-03 06:00:40.400 UTC [chaincodeCmd]
>   checkChaincodeCmdParams -> INFO 002 Using default escc 2019-05-03
>   06:00:40.400 UTC [chaincodeCmd] checkChaincodeCmdParams -> INFO 003
>   Using default vscc Error: could not assemble transaction, err proposal
>   response was not successful, error code 500, msg chaincode
>   registration failed: container exited with 1

I have already tried to update node js to version 10.x, but it didn't help.
Any idea what should I do?

Comment: I believe you are having the same issue as described here
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55856395/hyperledger-fabric-unable-to-instantiate-missing-contract-org-hyperledger-fa

Comment: I have also tried that, but it didn't work for me. Any other suggestion?

Comment: suggest you clean out all chaincode images as well otherwise it could re-use the old images. I usually do docker rmi $(docker images dev-* -q). If that doesn't work, then you could try deleting the contract-metadata folders for each of the contracts

Comment: Great, deleting the contract-metadata folders resolved my error! Thank you @david_k

Comment: Sorry, but I tried again with the same steps, and error is again appearing.. I assume that there is some bag or similar, and instantiating is confused during the process. Is there some more particular fix?

Comment: Make sure you clear out all old chaincode images "docker rmi $(docker images dev-* -q)" or you need to install and instantiate using a new version number otherwise you will use old chaincode images that don't contain your changes