# Hyperledger Fabric on VSCode, get error: Error instantiating smart contract: chaincode registration failed: container exited with 1

Tags: visual-studio-code, hyperledger-fabric

Using the IBM Blockchain extension on VSCode, I get the following error when trying to instantiate my Smart Contract on my channel: Error instantiating smart contract: chaincode registration failed: container exited with 1

I've tried deleting and building the smart contract package again.

Comment: It sounds like there is a problem with your chaincode. Are you declaring any contract-metadata ?

Comment: Hi. I am using the commercial paper tutorial from IBM.

Comment: Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55856395/hyperledger-fabric-unable-to-instantiate-missing-contract-org-hyperledger-fa as it is due to a problem with commercial paper which has now been fixed. It should work if you start again from scratch and ensure you pull the latest version of the fabric-samples repo

Answer (score 1):

List all the docker containers

> docker container ls

Stop the containers

> docker container stop *containerid*

Remove the container

> docker rm *containerid*

Answer (score 0):

Try deleting docker container

1. enlist all the docker container that is running from the terminal by
   running the following command  Docker container ls
2. Remove all the running container  docker rm [OPTIONS] CONTAINER
   [CONTAINER...]
3. docker container stop $(docker container ls -aq)
4. docker container rm $(docker container ls -aq)
5. docker image prune
6. docker volume prune

restart the network and install the package again